# With and Without "Else" under a IF statement in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to figure out the differences between the 2 versions below. One with "else" in the if statement, and one without, and im seeing the output are actually the same.

-------------------------- Version A - With 'Else'----------------------------

```
strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]

def test3(strs):
    ans = ''
    for i in range(min(len(strs[0]),len(strs[-1]))):    
        if strs[0][i] != strs[-1][i]:
            return ans
        **else**: ans += strs[0][i]
    return ans
    
test3(strs)
```

-------------------------- Version B - Without 'Else'----------------------------

```
def test3(strs):
    ans = ''
    for i in range(min(len(strs[0]),len(strs[-1]))):    
        if strs[0][i] != strs[-1][i]:
            return ans
        ans += strs[0][i]
    return ans
    
test3(strs)
```

Just wanna know if it always doesn't matter with or without 'else' in a for loop? (have the same output)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this specific case it makes no difference, because the result of the `if` is to do a `return`, which exits the function immediately, so any further code is not executed.

Comment: Mercury Wong, I don't think your question is strictly about Python 3 (as that behavior applies to pretty much any language with if/return statements). I've added "python" tag as suggested in "puthon-3.x" tag - feel free to [edit] the post to revert my change and clarify why the question is about puthon 3.

Comment: At this point, the Python 3 tag is probably redundant. `python` should imply Python 3; questions referring to the language that reached end-of-life over two years ago should use one of the Python-2-specific tags.

Comment: Just to note - this is a special case because of the return. It is not generally true for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Yes, they are the same. The reason is Python goes line by line evaluating your code, so if your statement about strs is true it means that it will return a value, this also ends the function (and loop with it) so it wouldn't move to the else block anyway. As such you can remove the else block as if the condition is true, it will execute the if block (returning something ending the function), if not it will move anyway to the next line which is to add part of strs to the answer.
For example

```py
def function(foo):
    if foo == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

is the same as

```py
def function(foo):
    if foo == True:
        return True
    return False
```

As if foo is true, it will return True and end the function if not it will either move to the else block and return False, or just return False as it is the next line. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

i think you have a great question
the answer is:
they actually do the same work but

the first code:

else block is executed only when the if block is false, and the ans variable is updated within the else block.
but the second code:

the else block is executed only when the if block is false, and the ans variable is updated immediately after the if block.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).